# Verify if input textbox is empty or null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm trying to make a registration form which returns an error message if the user didn't fill up all the textbox inputs.

What I have for now is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.LastName)
@Html.PasswordFor(r => r.Password)
@Html.PasswordFor(r => r.Password2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Email)
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Phone)
<input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
}
```

those are the fields that I want to check if they are null or empty

In my controller I have done an if statement to check if the email has already been used and it returns an error message but I wouldn't like to make an if statement for every field, that doesn't sound right.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Registration signingUp)
    {


        var db = new SolutiondbEntities();

        var FindEmail = db.tblProfiles.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PROF_Email == signingUp.Email);

        if (FindEmail == null)
        {
            var Data = db.tblProfiles.Create();

            Data.PROF_FirstName = signingUp.FirstName;
            Data.PROF_LastName = signingUp.LastName;
            Data.PROF_Password = signingUp.Password;
            Data.PROF_Email = signingUp.Email;
            Data.PROF_CellNum = signingUp.Phone;

            db.tblProfiles.Add(Data);

            int Saved = db.SaveChanges();

            if (Saved != 0)
            {
                Response.Write("Saved");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Something went wrong!");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Theres already an user with that Email");
        }


        return View();
    }
```

I would like to know how to check each field on the form for a null so I can return an error telling the user to fill all the blanks or fields.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's what I have in my model

```
public class Registration
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Password2 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT2:

I've added this lines of codes and it seems to work but not accurate as it will continue with the registration if any of the fields are not empty

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            if (Request.Form[key] == "")
            {
                Response.Write("Please, fill in all the fields");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Thanks for registering.");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

this works if I don't put anything in any of the fields, as soon as I put anything (even a space) it will continue..

Comment: Use Data Annotations (in this case `RequiredAttribute`) on your model (`Registration`) and framework will do it for you (with client side validation).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Could you make me an example of that, I've edited the question and added my model, I'm new to c#

Comment: What you have there when you say [DataType(DataType.Password)] is a Data Annotations. You can add a [Required()] Data Annotation for each field that you want to be required (i.e. cannot be null or empty string).

Comment: @AnneSchuessler I'm still able to continue with the registration even after adding [Required(ErrorMessage="Error")] to the top of every public string in the model. Do I have to add anything else in the controller? I'm new to c# and still learning beginner stuff

Comment: Make sure you check this stuff with javascript first (there are tons of examples out there). It saves you sending the data to server and back every time user tries to enter input, which makes things faster and easier on your server.

Comment: @maremp It might do things faster and easier but it can be evaded easily or be edited by front end users (correct me if I'm wrong) and cause trouble later, I would like to do it server side for safety.

Comment: " with javascript **first**." You are correct, but then again, I haven't said just JS. If you'd check with just on server side, that could get terribly slow. Checking with JS prevents sending the data on server by most users, if you also take correct security measures, you might make it work in a way that nobody could send you data directly. But I meant it more as a sidenote. Yes, absolutely check the data before storing in on server/database.

Comment: @Johhan you have to do it in **both** places. First step client side validation so user won't need to wait for server validation (and you won't use bandwidth) and then server side (because JS may be disabled/unavailable or...bypassed by malicious user). Check examples about unobtrusive JS with ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I want to do it on both server side and front end eventually but I'm trying to do the hardest one first which is for me the server side one. The RequiredAttribute didn't seem to do it, it still goes with the registration normally even if it's empty.

I edited the question and added a few lines of codes I tried but yeah, it doesn't work as it suppose to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all with [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.98).aspx). First of all, I'd like to remind you that validation must be done on both the server-side and client-side. If you do it only on the server then you'll have a post just to know model errors (and this will consume time and bandwidth). If you do it only on the client then you'll be open to malicious posts or you won't detect validation error because JavaScript is disabled.

How to do it? Let's first pick your model and add proper annotations:

```
public class Registration
{
    [Required] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password), Required] public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Password2 { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Please note you may/should add all possible validations (password matching, e-mail, and phone number regex). Using proper annotations (see first link) will allow you to have better validation rules (for example `FirstName` must be at least two non-whitespace characters, the e-mail must be a valid address, and so on). Let's see a quick example (let's check MSDN about individual attributes for more details and a better usage):

```
public class Registration
{
    [Required, MinLength(2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [Required, MinLength(2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Password), Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    [Required, Compare("Password")]
    public string Password2 { get; set; }
    
    [Required, EMailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [Required, Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

If you did enable unobtrusive JavaScript (and required HTML code) then it's all you need for client-side validation.

Server-side is even easier because the model binder will do everything for you, you just need to [check if the model is valid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or not:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Registration signingUp)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(signingUp);

    // Model is valid, work with it... 
}
```

Note that you're not (strictly) required to check if the model is valid or not, if you have the same constraint in your database then it'll throw an exception when trying to insert a new record. The user will get back a not so meaningful (from his perspective) error message so I suggest always do this check.

Comment: OMG, you're a life saver, I wish I could upvote you but I need reputation or something. Thank you very much sir.